# How to compile multiple standalone C++ program in a single Visual Studio Code Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to compile single standalone C++ programs in Visual Studio Code. Currently, when I compile a program in VS Code, it only outputs a single executable file. If I have one program *helloworld.cpp*, it will only compile and create a *helloworld.exe* in the folder.

If I want to create another program, for example, *Test1.cpp* the executable should be named *Test1.exe* in the same folder and so on.

[image]

Comment: If you want to do anything complex, such as "make one exectutable for every .cpp file in a project folder", make a CMake script to do it: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html . VS code has a plugin for CMake that can run the script.

Comment: And what is the problem? Don't you get Test1.exe when you compile Test1.cpp? Any errors? Can you [edit] your question to clarify? You may also want to read [ask].

Comment: Clarification of the meaning of the question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the IDE -  `.cpp` or `.c` files are not "program", they are [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). Compiler creates an object file from each translation unit, and than linker create a "program" if it can find a spectial function - **`main`**.

So, if you want to compile multiple program, you should create a separate project within your solution. I guess, in MSVS Code you can add a new project to existing solution. If you use CMake this equivalent to add `add_executable` for each program.